# Creating Object on the basis of type base on a condition

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am facing a unique problem. We have a download functionality in our application in which we have a drop-down which contains type of file user need to download i.e. pdf,csv or excel

To implement this problem we have create one Interface IFileDownaload and three different class clsCSV,ClsPDF and clsExcel which are implemented by IFileDownaload

Now my problem is how to inititate a class on the basis of Dropdown value because i dont want to write down if-else statement

if(option=="pdf") type

because in future if we introduce a new file download type then it will impact us to re-write whole logic again

Any suggestion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Have a search for 'factory pattern'.

Comment: I think factory pattern are conditional basis all depend upon if-else or switch case.In my case i think DI or IOC is more suitable but my problem is How to create object on the basis of drop-down value.

I have also set dropdown option as clsPDF,clsCSV but somewhere stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can define abbreviation for each class you have, so that you'll have something like this:

```
public interface IFileDownload
{
    string Abbreviation { get; }
}

public class PDFDonwload : IFileDownload
{
    public string Abbreviation { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can make some class, i.e. factory, which have instances of all filedownloaders you have and which iterates through their Abbreviations till it finds proper class. It can be implemented like this:

```
public static class DownloadHander
    {

    private static List<IFileDownload> _handlers; 
    static DownloadHander()
    {
        _handlers = new List<IFileDownload>();
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        _handlers.Add(new PDFDonwload());
    }

    public static Stream HandleDownload(string abbreviation)
    {
        foreach (var fileDownload in _handlers)
        {
            if (fileDownload.Abbreviation == abbreviation)
            {
                //and here you make a stream for client
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No Handler");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but if I have to use 
if (fileDownload.Abbreviation == abbreviation)
            {
                //and here you make a stream for client
            }
then can't I do in the initial stage also, In this approach also whenever we are writing new functionality we have to add that on handler also.

So I think it's not completing our objective

Comment: @user3886602, Well, you can load handler via reflection in runtime, but i think it's overkill. In fact, you have only 2 solutions: first is to add handlers in compile-time by modifying code and my code gives you strongly-types solution for this way.
Another solution is to load handlers from assemblies in runtime. I can provide you a code to start for this approach, but i don't think it will be cool, cause it'll make your app more complicated

Comment: But dosn't initialize every object in advance is an overhead and violate design principle.

Comment: I'm confused - do the individual downloaders need to be initialised before being used?

Comment: Initialization of downloaders  is not a huge problem. You can define some Initialize method in interface, or use DI, or any another approach. I think the question is, what approach to use: compile-time or runtime. Now i understand, that i would prefer runtime-way and store assemblies with implementations in special folder

Comment: You can have the best of both worlds - many DI containers will scan folders for assemblies which implement a certain interface, and register them automatically. But I suspect 'initialise' in this context actually means 'instantiate'...

Comment: @SteveWilkes Of course you can, you're absolutely right:) But, i didn't undestand, what exactly TS wants, and so do you, as i see... )

Comment: Oh well, you can only write answers, the rest is up to them :) I've up-voted your answer for your trouble :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all for providing there valuable comments.

Answer (score 1):

When I have a number of classes which implement a certain type and those classes are stateless [services](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design) rather than [entities](http://lostechies.com/joeocampo/2007/04/15/a-discussion-on-domain-driven-design-entities), I use a [Registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) rather than a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Your Registry has instances of all the `IFileDownload`-implementing classes injected into it in an array:

```
public class FileDownloaderRegistry
{
    private readonly IFileDownload[] _downloaders;

    public FileDownloaderRegistry(IFileDownload[] downloaders)
    {
        _downloaders = downloaders;
    }
}
```

You then have a property on `IFileDownload` which indicates the file type handled by the downloader:

```
public interface IFileDownload
{
    string FileType { get; }
    // etc.
}
```

And finally a method on your Registry which takes the file type and delegates the work to the appropriate downloader:

```
public string DownloadFile(string fileName, string fileType)
{
    var handlingDownloader = _downloaders
        .FirstOrDefault(d => d.FileType == fileType);

    if (handlingDownloader == null) 
    {
        // Probably throw an Exception
    }

    return handlingDownloader.Download(fileName);
}
```

DI containers will often implicitly understand arrays, so just registering the various `IFileDownload`s should end up with them in the array injected into the Registry's constructor. *e.g.* with StructureMap you use:

```
For<IFileDownload>().Use<ClsCSV>();
For<IFileDownload>().Use<ClsPDF>();
For<IFileDownload>().Use<ClsExcel>();
```

Adding a new `IFileDownload` is then a matter of writing the class and [adding it to the set of `IFileDownload`s registered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) with your DI container. You can also have the container manage the lifetimes of each object so (if they're stateless) they're only instantiated once each, when they're first needed.